# why div position change when a page loading?

Tags: css, html

I have a top banner div, a left navigation pane div and a content div. A new web page will load the content div when a link is clicked.(links are in the left navigation pane div. My issue is when a new page loading to content div, top banner div position goes up, then the text of that div also goes up.)

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML code, including any Javascript and/or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Without the source it's tough to be sure, but it sounds like you need to use a position property on the div. Give a try to `Position:relative`

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer. Please wait until you have 50 rep or more, otherwise remove this answer.